# nltk Lemmatizer TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, nltk

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
import self as self

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '.', ',', '~']

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(self, word) for word in words if word and word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

print("words")
```

When I run my code, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' will show.
I don't know how to solve this error please help. Thank you.

Comment: after replace it, still having same error

Comment: Could you add the full traceback please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.